# No root view controller error on Xcode 5

Tags: xcode

I get this error on Xcode 5:

```
Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch
```

My code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    [Flurry startSession:@"HJ4X7X6PB3942VGHQWWZ"];
    screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
    if (screenRect.size.height > 500)
    {
        isFive = YES;
        NSLog(@"is iPhone 5");
    }else{
        isFive = NO;
    }
    [[SQLiteOperator sharedOperator] openDatabase];
    [self setupLang];
    [self handleTabBarLanguage];
    [self handleAppUpdatePopUpLanguage];

    _banner_view_controller = [[BannerViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BannerViewController" bundle:nil];
    [_banner_view_controller send_request];
    [_banner_view_controller didHidden];
    [_navigation_controller.view addSubview:_banner_view_controller.view];
    [CoreData sharedCoreData].banner_view_controller = _banner_view_controller;


    // Create content and menu controllers
    //
    DEMONavigationController *navigationController = [[DEMONavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[DEMOHomeViewController alloc] init]];
    DEMOMenuViewController *menuController = [[DEMOMenuViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];

    // Create frosted view controller
    //
    REFrostedViewController *frostedViewController = [[REFrostedViewController alloc] initWithContentViewController:navigationController menuViewController:menuController];
    frostedViewController.direction = REFrostedViewControllerDirectionLeft;
    frostedViewController.liveBlurBackgroundStyle = REFrostedViewControllerLiveBackgroundStyleLight;

    // Make it a root controller
    //
    self.window.rootViewController = frostedViewController;
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using storyboard click on the project name in project navigator in Xcode.  Then look for deployment info. Select Main Interface as your storyboard name. In app delegate.m

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
//    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
//    // Override point for customization after application launch.
//    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
//    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

And now try it.

Comment: Worked for me! all you have to do is comment out the three lines in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions in your appDelegate.m.